# Is filling a DataTable necessary for just setting variables with 2 column values?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to improve performance of an application, I have a case where a common SPROC is being used but is it necessary to fill a DataTable just to set 2 variable values?

Is there anything more efficient?

```
Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DB").ConnectionString)
Dim CmdUsers As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("uspGetUsers", Conn)

CmdUsers.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

CmdUsers.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserName", Session("UserID")))

Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dtUserInfo As DataTable = New DataTable

da = New SqlDataAdapter(CmdUsers)
da.Fill(dtUserInfo)

isParent = dtUserInfo.Rows(0)("IsAdmin")
UserVal = dtUserInfo.Rows(0)("UserVal")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SqlDataReader is the fastest way to read data from a query. Try the following:

```
  Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DB").ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("uspGetUsers", conn)
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session("UserID"))
      Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
          isParent = reader("IsAdmin")
          UserVal = reader("UserVal")
        End While
      End Using
    End Using
  End Using
```

You may need to parse the data to the correct types.

Also, note the use of Using to automatically dispose of the connection, command and reader objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/htd05whh.aspx